# How to publish your key used to sign deb packages so you will be able to use your repository from any machine?

Tags: apt, deb, gnupg, signature

I am looking for a solution that would prevent me from seeing things like:

`W: GPG error: http://updates.example.com lenny Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 00AABBCCDDEE0011`

The question applies for both Debian and Ubuntu.

Isn't possible to publish the key somewhere where it can be automatically downloaded by apt-get based on it's signature?

Note: I know that I can put my signature to an we server and use wget to get it and install it from there, still I am using for a better solution.

Comment: Try `apt-get install debian-archive-keyring` Courtesy: http://www.howtoforge.com/debian-lenny-public-key-is-not-available-NO_PUBKEY-9AA38DCD55BE302B

Comment: Nope, this didn't fix the problem. The KEY is from a thirdparty.

Comment: Did you try: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 00AABBCCDDEE0011`

Comment: Yes, it worked, make it an answer. BTW, is there a way to auto-add these keys when you add an apt-repository (like a single command or so?)

Comment: Added as answer.

Comment: As for auto adding I don't know of a way for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 00AABBCCDDEE0011
```