# key import with apt-add-repository and own repository possible?

Tags: apt, repository, gnupg, reprepro

Is it possible to use the public-gpg-key import feature of apt-add-repository with my own reprepro repository? Is there e.g. something like a default key server where apt-add-repository expects to find the keys or a path within the (http) repository where it will look for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `apt-add-repository` and `add-apt-repository` have a -k option you can use to specify your own public keyring repository. `apt-key` can add the fingerprint of the key you control and trust. Of course you can simply add a public key to the keyserver.ubuntu.com or other keyserver rather than using your own keyserver, but apt still must be told they key fingerprints. See Saji89's helpful answer about `apt-key` at https://askubuntu.com/a/217529/63886 (and vote it up if it proves useful to you).

You can also use medibuntu's approach as automation if many computers are involved. Here's how [medibuntu.org](http://www.medibuntu.org/repository.php) does it:

```
sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list  http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update `
```

That is followed up by installing a couple more packages once the repo has been added.

---

As explanation:

```
sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list`
```

adds the repo itself to your configuration.

```
sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

Updates the apt-get information from the new (and all other repos).

```
sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring
```

Installs the public key for the repository. The `--allow-unauthenticated` is how you avoid the chicken and egg problem.

`sudo apt-get --quiet update`

Updates apt again.

Then application data and debugging hooks packages are added for their applications.

You can browse their repo http://packages.medibuntu.org/ to see how their packages do the job.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer, John! I have indeed published the public key to keyserver.ubuntu.com and thought `apt-add-repository` would fetch the key from there. But this seems to fail. I don't know why, because even with `-m` the output is not very detailed.

At the moment I am just deploying a deb-package, that includes the key. In the post install script of the package the repository gets added and the key is imported. Could be worse, but having a one-liner would be nicer. Especially since `apt-add-repository` seemed to offer that capability.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about whether `add-apt-repository` will work with your own repo that you host yourself rather than on Launchpad, the answer is "No", and with good reason.

The `add-apt-repository` tool provides a cryptographically strong trust relationship to valid Launchpad PPAs. What it can't guarantee is that you should trust the Launchpad users who have upload access to a given PPA, but it still provides a good audit trail and a guarantee that packages at least come from the claimed PPA.

If what you were asking for was possible, it would have no trust guarantee at all and would be more or less equivalent to Windows users downloading random things from random websites at random moments in time.

Is there a good reason why you need to use your own repo, why you can't use a PPA?

Comment: Okay, then `add-apt-repository` should be renamed to `add-ppa-repository`.

You are right, you have to trust the developer or maintainer to not break your system or sneak in bad stuff. But that is the same for PPAs and own repositories. In that regard there is nothing special about PPAs. If you are adding 3rd party repositories to your system you **should** trust them or you shouldn't add the repository.

We are using our own repositories for proprietary customer software and deployment of modified packages within closed networks. Nothing that would fit PPA.